# C# datatypes in AS3

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, byte, short

I'm porting some C# decompression code to AS3, and since it's doing some pretty complex stuff, it's using a range of datatypes such as `byte` and `short`. The problem is, AS3 doesn't have those datatypes.

For the most part I can use `uint` to hold these values. However, at some points, I get a line such as:

```
length[symbol++] = (short)len;
```

To my understanding, this means that `len` must be read and assigned to the `length` array as a `short`. So I'm wondering, how would I do this in AS3? I'm guessing perhaps to do:

```
length[symbol++] = len & 0xFF;
```

But I'm unsure if this would give a proper result.

So basically, my question is this: how do I make sure to keep the the correct number of bytes when doing this sort of stuff in AS3? Maybe I should use `ByteArray`s instead?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on reason why cast is in C# code you may or may not need to keep cast in AS3 code. If cast is purely to adjust type to type of elements of `length` array (i.e. there is no loss of precision) than you don't need cast. If `len` can actually be bigger than 0x7FFF you'll need to perform some cast.

I think `ByteArray` maybe a reasonable option if you need to handle result similar to C# `StreamReader`, random access may be harder than necessary.

Note that `short` is 2 bytes long (synonym for `System.Int16`) so to convert to it using bit manipulations you need to do `& 0xFFFF`. Be also very careful if casting between signed and unsigned types...

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I meant `0xFFFF` not `0xFF`. I was thinking to use `ByteArray`, but the thing is that I need the value as a single numerical variable, rather than an array of bytes. So would `& 0xFFFF` give a desirable result?